# How to store Firebase Auth users' credentials on device to quickly switch accounts later?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I want to implement the UX where it is possible to quickly switch between previously signed in Firebase Auth users e.g. from a navigation drawer like Google apps do:

[image: Account switcher]

The problem is that Firebase docs and samples only implement the "sign in - sign out" flow, where switching users would require signing out first and then reentering a password / repeating auth flow with Facebook etc., instead of just switching with a single tap. Google advocates for Smart Lock, but it's only good for email and Google auth providers, and is generally not the UX I'm seeking.

What is the proper way to store those users and their credentials? The solution must support users authenticated via any of the supported providers, such as email/password, Google, Facebook, etc.

Since authenticating with either method results in obtaining an `AuthCredential` object, perhaps the question boils down to how to securely store those objects on the device, and whether they can be reused later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not store credentials on the device. Best way to do so currently is to initialize multiple Firebase App instances and keep an array of these apps. You would sign in the user on each app.

Refer to [initializeApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#initializeApp(android.content.Context,%20com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions,%20java.lang.String)) API.

You can then access an App's Auth instance via: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseAppInstance)`.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Setting up and managing multiple FirebaseApp instances sounds like a lot of overhead though. I hope they implement this use case in a more lean way in the future.

Waiting a few more days for alternative answers, then marking this one as accepted if nothing better is suggested.